# 403 forbidden while creating admin user in Riak-CS

Tags: cloud, storage, riak, cloud-storage

I'm following guidelines and set up anomimous user creation

```
 cat  /etc/riak-cs/app.config  | grep anonymous_user_creation
 {anonymous_user_creation, true},
```

and using post request to create admin user:

> curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>     -X POST `http://localhost:8080/riak-cs/user` \
>     --data '{"email":"foobar@example.com", "name":"admin user"}'

The response always is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>ServiceUnavailable</Code><Message>Please reduce your request rate.</Message><Resource>/riak-cs/user</Resource><RequestId></RequestId></Error>
```

No matter how long I wait (hours) between requests.

Additional information:

Checking whether stanchion  ip is correct:

```
root@q092:~# cat /etc/riak-cs/app.config | grep stanchion
              {stanchion_ip, "127.0.0.1"},
              {stanchion_port, 8085 },
              {stanchion_ssl, false },
              %% the admin credentials specified in the stanchion
root@q092:~# cat /etc/riak-cs/app.config | grep stanchion
              {stanchion_ip, "127.0.0.1"},
              {stanchion_port, 8085 },
              {stanchion_ssl, false },
              %% the admin credentials specified in the stanchion
root@q092:~# cat /etc/stanchion/app.config | grep stanchion
 {stanchion, [
                   {stanchion_ip, "127.0.0.1"},
                   {stanchion_port, 8085 } ,
                                            {"/var/log/stanchion/error.log", error, 10485760, "$D0", 5},
                                            {"/var/log/stanchion/console.log", info, 10485760, "$D0", 5}
          {crash_log, "/var/log/stanchion/crash.log"},
root@q092:~# cat /var/log/stanchion/error.log
```

pinging stanchion:

```
root@q092:~# stanchion ping
pong
```

The riak-cs error log is more interesting:

```
cat /var/log/riak-cs/error.log.0 
2013-06-14 19:41:22.285 [error] <0.131.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.131.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {tcp,econnrefused} in gen_server:init_it/6 line 320
2013-06-14 19:42:06.562 [error] <0.129.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.129.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {tcp,econnrefused} in gen_server:init_it/6 line 320
2013-06-14 19:43:55.024 [error] <0.131.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.131.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {tcp,econnrefused} in gen_server:init_it/6 line 320
2013-06-14 19:43:59.664 [error] <0.131.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.131.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {tcp,econnrefused} in gen_server:init_it/6 line 320
2013-06-14 20:00:46.381 [error] <0.131.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.131.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {tcp,econnrefused} in gen_server:init_it/6 line 320
2013-06-14 20:01:14.355 [error] <0.129.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.129.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {tcp,econnrefused} in gen_server:init_it/6 line 320
2013-06-14 20:02:03.254 [error] <0.131.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.131.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {tcp,econnrefused} in gen_server:init_it/6 line 320
2013-06-14 21:07:21.845 [error] <0.262.0> Supervisor poolboy_sup had child riak_cs_riakc_pool_worker started with riak_cs_riakc_pool_worker:start_link([{name,{local,bucket_list_pool}},{worker_module,riak_cs_riakc_pool_worker},{size,5},{max_overflow,...},...]) at undefined exit with reason shutdown in context shutdown_error
```

Comment: {tcp, econnrefused} indicates that something is not listening where it is expected.  Have you verified that Riak is listening on the port Riak CS is configured to connect to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is unfortunately a bit misleading.

User creation is one of the request types that is serialized via stanchion, and this error tends to appear when stanchion is not running or configured correctly. [See this link for more details](http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/tutorials/fast-track/Building-a-Local-Test-Environment/).

Comment: stanchion ping
pong
And I seem to followed instructions very closely. What additional debug information is available?

Comment: Is both Riak and Stanchion running and listening to on the ports that Riak-CS expects prior to Riak-CS being started?

Comment: It appears I've misconfigurated riak backend. Now fixed it thanks for help and information.